# How to add a map scale in MapView on Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm struggling with adding a map scale that displays current length on screen depending on current zoom level. I'm having a feeling that it might exist some predefined class to use but I have no clue...? I've searched around a lot but can't find anything.

Any help i much appreciated =)

// Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I got it now! Luis answer helped me a lot and also OpenStreetMap. Here's what I came up with:

```
<your.own.package.path>;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.location.Location;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;
import com.iqqn.uppgift5.GameMapActivity;

public class ScaleBarOverlay extends Overlay{

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    // Defaults

    boolean enabled = true;

    float xOffset = 10;
    float yOffset = 10;
    float lineWidth = 2;
    int textSize = 12;

    boolean imperial = false;
    boolean nautical = false;

    boolean latitudeBar = true;
    boolean longitudeBar = false;

    // Internal

    protected final MapView mapView;
    protected final GameMapActivity master;

    private Context context;

    protected final Picture scaleBarPicture = new Picture();
    private final Matrix scaleBarMatrix = new Matrix();

    private int lastZoomLevel = -1;

    float xdpi;
    float ydpi;
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    public ScaleBarOverlay(Context _context, GameMapActivity master, MapView mapView) {
        super();

        this.master = master;
        this.context = _context;
        this.mapView = mapView;

        xdpi = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
        ydpi = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi;

        screenWidth = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        screenHeight = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    /**
     * @return the enabled
     */
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @param enabled the enabled to set
     */
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @return the lineWidth
     */
    public float getLineWidth() {
        return lineWidth;
    }

    /**
     * @param lineWidth the lineWidth to set
     */
    public void setLineWidth(float lineWidth) {
        this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    }

    /**
     * @return the imperial
     */
    public boolean isImperial() {
        return imperial;
    }

    /**
     * @param imperial the imperial to set
     */
    public void setImperial() {
        this.imperial = true;
        this.nautical = false;
        createScaleBarPicture();
    }

    /**
     * @return the nautical
     */
    public boolean isNautical() {
        return nautical;
    }

    /**
     * @param nautical the nautical to set
     */
    public void setNautical() {
        this.nautical = true;
        this.imperial = false;
        createScaleBarPicture();
    }

    public void setMetric() {
        this.nautical = false;
        this.imperial = false;
        createScaleBarPicture();
    }

    public void drawLatitudeScale(boolean latitude) {
        this.latitudeBar = latitude;
    }

    public void drawLongitudeScale(boolean longitude) {
        this.longitudeBar = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView localMapView, boolean shadow) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            // Draw the overlay
            if (shadow == false) {
                final int zoomLevel = localMapView.getZoomLevel();

                if (zoomLevel != lastZoomLevel) {
                    lastZoomLevel = zoomLevel;
                    createScaleBarPicture();
                }

                this.scaleBarMatrix.setTranslate(-1 * (scaleBarPicture.getWidth() / 2 - 0.5f), -1 * (scaleBarPicture.getHeight() / 2 - 0.5f));
                this.scaleBarMatrix.postTranslate(xdpi/2, ydpi/2 + canvas.getHeight()-50);

                canvas.save();
                canvas.setMatrix(scaleBarMatrix);
                canvas.drawPicture(scaleBarPicture);
                canvas.restore();
            }
        }
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================

    public void disableScaleBar() {
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    public boolean enableScaleBar() {
        return this.enabled = true;
    }

    private void createScaleBarPicture() {
        // We want the scale bar to be as long as the closest round-number miles/kilometers
        // to 1-inch at the latitude at the current center of the screen.

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        if (projection == null) {
            return;
        }

        Location locationP1 = new Location("ScaleBar location p1");
        Location locationP2 = new Location("ScaleBar location p2");

        // Two points, 1-inch apart in x/latitude, centered on screen
        GeoPoint p1 = projection.fromPixels((int) ((screenWidth / 2) - (xdpi / 2)), screenHeight/2);
        GeoPoint p2 = projection.fromPixels((int) ((screenWidth / 2) + (xdpi / 2)), screenHeight/2);

        locationP1.setLatitude(p1.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        locationP2.setLatitude(p2.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        locationP1.setLongitude(p1.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        locationP2.setLongitude(p2.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);

        float xMetersPerInch = locationP1.distanceTo(locationP2);

        p1 = projection.fromPixels(screenWidth/2, (int) ((screenHeight / 2) - (ydpi / 2)));
        p2 = projection.fromPixels(screenWidth/2, (int) ((screenHeight / 2) + (ydpi / 2)));

        locationP1.setLatitude(p1.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        locationP2.setLatitude(p2.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        locationP1.setLongitude(p1.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        locationP2.setLongitude(p2.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);

        float yMetersPerInch =  locationP1.distanceTo(locationP2);

        final Paint barPaint = new Paint();
        barPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        barPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        barPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        barPaint.setAlpha(255);

        final Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setAlpha(255);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);

        final Canvas canvas = scaleBarPicture.beginRecording((int)xdpi, (int)ydpi);

        if (latitudeBar) {
            String xMsg = scaleBarLengthText(xMetersPerInch, imperial, nautical);
            Rect xTextRect = new Rect();
            textPaint.getTextBounds(xMsg, 0, xMsg.length(), xTextRect);

            int textSpacing = (int)(xTextRect.height() / 5.0);

            canvas.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + xdpi, yOffset + lineWidth, barPaint);
            canvas.drawRect(xOffset + xdpi, yOffset, xOffset + xdpi + lineWidth, yOffset + xTextRect.height() + lineWidth + textSpacing, barPaint);

            if (!longitudeBar) {
                canvas.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + lineWidth, yOffset + xTextRect.height() + lineWidth + textSpacing, barPaint);
            }
            canvas.drawText(xMsg, (xOffset + xdpi/2 - xTextRect.width()/2), (yOffset + xTextRect.height() + lineWidth + textSpacing), textPaint);
        }

        if (longitudeBar) {
            String yMsg = scaleBarLengthText(yMetersPerInch, imperial, nautical);
            Rect yTextRect = new Rect();
            textPaint.getTextBounds(yMsg, 0, yMsg.length(), yTextRect);

            int textSpacing = (int)(yTextRect.height() / 5.0);

            canvas.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + lineWidth, yOffset + ydpi, barPaint);
            canvas.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset + ydpi, xOffset + yTextRect.height() + lineWidth + textSpacing, yOffset + ydpi + lineWidth, barPaint);

            if (! latitudeBar) {
                canvas.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset, xOffset + yTextRect.height() + lineWidth + textSpacing, yOffset + lineWidth, barPaint);
            }                       

            float x = xOffset + yTextRect.height() + lineWidth + textSpacing;
            float y = yOffset + ydpi/2 + yTextRect.width()/2;

            canvas.rotate(-90, x, y);
            canvas.drawText(yMsg, x, y + textSpacing, textPaint);

        }

        scaleBarPicture.endRecording();
    }

    private String scaleBarLengthText(float meters, boolean imperial, boolean nautical) {
        if (this.imperial) {
            if (meters >= 1609.344) {
                return (meters / 1609.344) + "mi";
            } else if (meters >= 1609.344/10) {
                return ((meters / 160.9344) / 10.0) + "mi";
            } else {
                return (meters * 3.2808399) + "ft";
            }
        } else if (this.nautical) {
            if (meters >= 1852) {
                return ((meters / 1852)) + "nm";
            } else if (meters >= 1852/10) {
                return (((meters / 185.2)) / 10.0) + "nm";
            } else {
                return ((meters * 3.2808399)) + "ft";
            }
        } else {
            if (meters >= 1000) {
                return ((meters / 1000)) + "km";
            } else if (meters > 100) {
                return ((meters / 100.0) / 10.0) + "km";
            } else {
                return meters + "m";
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) {
        // Do not react to screen taps.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it the following way in your onCreate():

```
...
scaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this.getBaseContext(), this, myMapView);
List<Overlay> overlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
// Add scale bar overlay
scaleBarOverlay.setMetric();
overlays.add(scaleBarOverlay);
...
```

Hope this will help anyone =) This will work from API level 7+. I haven't tested it on API level 14+ though, and i know that some hardware accelerated stuff "don't" work there like drawing a picture with canvas. But i think it'll work with a recording.

Thanks again Luis!

// Alexander

Comment: To get the code working for your own implementation, just remove `GameMapActivity master` from `ScaleBarOverlay` and you have a fully working and usable class for your own implementation!

Comment: There is a bug in your code. You need to refresh the scale bar on every camera change, not just zoom change (scale bar length depends on latitude too).

Comment: Yes, this is true. Truth is i locked my mapview to only allow navigation in (X,Y). Not rotation. That will be a good exercise for anyone that wants to use this ;) For anyone interested, OpenStreetMap has a very fine implementation that'll work on all API levels >= 14. Look here for more information: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ScaleBarOverlay.java

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there isn't a predifined class to do that.

One possibility is to create an overlay that checks current longitude span, as it changes accordingly to latitude,  and then draw the scale at the correct size.

Bellow you can find an example on how to do that:

**ScaleBar Overlay**

```
public class CopyOfScaleBarOverlay extends Overlay {    
private static final String STR_M = "m"; 
private static final String STR_KM = "km"; 

//Constants
private static float scaleBarProportion = 0.25f;
private float cMarginLeft=4;
private float cLineTopSize=8;
private float cMarginTop=6;
private float cMarginBottom=2;
private float cTextSize=12;
private float distanceFromBottom=100;


//instantiation
private Context context;

private Paint paintLine, paintText, paintRectangle;
private Location l0;
private Location l1;
private float ds;
private int width, height, pi;
private float marginLeft, marginTop, marginBottom, lineTopSize;
private String unit;



public CopyOfScaleBarOverlay(Context context){
    super();
    this.context=context;

    paintText= new TextPaint();
    paintText.setARGB(180, 0, 0, 0);
    paintText.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintText.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    paintRectangle = new Paint();
    paintRectangle.setARGB(80,255,255,255);
    paintRectangle.setAntiAlias(true);

    paintLine = new Paint();
    paintLine.setARGB(180, 0, 0, 0);
    paintLine.setAntiAlias(true);

    l0 = new Location("none");
    l1 = new Location("none");

    ds=this.context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    width=this.context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    height=this.context.getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    pi = (int) (height - distanceFromBottom *ds);

    marginLeft=cMarginLeft*ds;
    lineTopSize=cLineTopSize*ds;
    marginTop=cMarginTop*ds;
    marginBottom=cMarginBottom*ds;


}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapview, boolean shadow) {
    super.draw(canvas, mapview, shadow);
    if(mapview.getZoomLevel() > 1){

        //Calculate scale bar size and units
        GeoPoint g0 = mapview.getProjection().fromPixels(0, height/2);
        GeoPoint g1 = mapview.getProjection().fromPixels(width, height/2);
        l0.setLatitude(g0.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        l0.setLongitude(g0.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        l1.setLatitude(g1.getLatitudeE6()/1E6);
        l1.setLongitude(g1.getLongitudeE6()/1E6);
        float d01=l0.distanceTo(l1);
        float d02=d01*scaleBarProportion;
        // multiply d02 by a unit conversion factor if needed
        float cd02;
        if(d02 > 1000){
            unit = STR_KM;
            cd02 = d02 / 1000;
        } else{
            unit = STR_M;
            cd02 = d02;
        }
        int i=1;
        do{
            i *=10;
        }while (i <= cd02);
        i/=10;
        float dcd02=(int)(cd02/i)*i;
        float bs=dcd02*width/d01*d02/cd02;

        String text=String.format("%.0f %s", dcd02, unit);
        paintText.setTextSize(cTextSize * ds);
        float text_x_size=paintText.measureText(text);
        float x_size = bs + text_x_size/2 + 2*marginLeft;

        //Draw rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(0,pi,x_size,pi+marginTop+paintText.getFontSpacing()+marginBottom, paintRectangle);

        //Draw line
        canvas.drawLine(marginLeft, pi+marginTop, marginLeft + bs, pi+marginTop, paintLine);
        //Draw line tops
        canvas.drawLine(marginLeft, pi+marginTop - lineTopSize/2, marginLeft, pi+marginTop + lineTopSize/2, paintLine);
        canvas.drawLine(marginLeft +bs, pi+marginTop - lineTopSize/2, marginLeft+bs, pi+marginTop + lineTopSize/2, paintLine);
        //Draw line midle
        canvas.drawLine(marginLeft + bs/2, pi+marginTop - lineTopSize/3, marginLeft + bs/2, pi+marginTop + lineTopSize/3, paintLine);
        //Draw line quarters
        canvas.drawLine(marginLeft + bs/4, pi+marginTop - lineTopSize/4, marginLeft + bs/4, pi+marginTop + lineTopSize/4, paintLine);
        canvas.drawLine(marginLeft + 3*bs/4, pi+marginTop - lineTopSize/4, marginLeft + 3*bs/4, pi+marginTop + lineTopSize/4, paintLine);

        //Draw text
        canvas.drawText(text, marginLeft +bs, pi+marginTop+paintText.getFontSpacing(), paintText);
    }
}
```

}

**To use**

On your activity that extendes `MapActivity`, add the following:

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(new CopyOfScaleBarOverlay(this));
```

**Note**

The example is using metric units. To use a different unit system, multiply `d02` in the code above by a unit conversion factor and adjust strings with the unit name.

Enjoy it.

Comment: Ahh, nice! Worked like a charm! But i looked at how open streetmap did, and modified their code to work with google maps. I think my way will minimize the required memory usage and also the execution-time in onDraw()...