# Display scale iOS Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Do you know how to display map scale on Google Maps in iOS?
I made a research, but I didn't find anything about it. I checked google maps documentation too.

Comment: There isn't a built-in way of making a scale control within Google Maps SDK iOS. I found only this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964608/how-to-add-a-map-scale-in-mapview-on-android), but it's for Android.

Comment: Thanks. I saw it. It's strange that Google didn't implement scale bar in their library.